# Using import statements in a submodule's init.py file in Python

Tags: python

I have the following folder structure:

```
- a/
  - test.py
  - b/
    - __init__.py (empty)
    - c/
      __init.py (imports classes from x.py and z.py)
      x.py
      z.py
```

`test.py` content:

```
from b.c import SomeClient
```

I'm trying to import `c` in `test.py`, but receiving the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'c'
```

The contents of the `__init__.py` under the `c/` folder looks like this:

```
from c.x import SomeClient
from c.z import AnotherClient
```

I tried removing the `c.` pointer from the import statements, but it starts throwing errors saying there is no module named `x` or `z`.

Answer (score 0):

The file `a/b/c/__init__.py` imports files relative to `c`. The problem is that the usage of [implicit relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-import-system) (and also in this [reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)) has already been removed in Python3:

> There is no longer any implicit import machinery

Either use absolute imports in your `a/b/c/__init__.py`

```
from b.c.x import SomeClient
from b.c.z import AnotherClient
```

Or explicit relative imports

```
from .x import SomeClient
from .z import AnotherClient
```

If that is not possible, just set `PYTHONPATH` to point to where the `c` directory can be found so that Python can see the modules in it when imported. If in Linux:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/a/b
```

Comment: I tried that, however, the imported classes also have `import` statements starting with `c.` prefix, and the contents of the `c/` folder are generated by a generator (openapi-generator), there is no way I can go in there and update all the import statements everytime that folder is generated. 

Comment: I updated the answer to set `PYTHONPATH` in your executing environment. Does it work on your side now?

Comment: this is going to be in a django project; isn't there a way of doing this without a setup step(no need to update the pythonpath etc)?

Comment: Without updating the files inside `c` directory? You may try making an explicit relative import such as `from .x import SomeClient` but I assume you can't change the files under `c` directory right?

Comment: From my perspective, since all codes inside `c` directory access it based on the root `c`, then you really have to include the path to `c` in the paths that are searched by Python for modules. One way is through @U12-Forward's answer or my answer with setting `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Also if that is a django project, I assume that at some point, you have to call `manage.py` like if you need to perform `makemigrations` and `migrate`. I assume that for you to call that, you would be setting `PYTHONPATH` as an environment variable anyways, probably.